# Bad Magic Number error when trying to Decrypt file in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I'm using Latest version of OpenSSL for Windows, I'm trying to decrypt a message `U2FsdGVkX18ztmw81FTK/c+jAf8xtcZdIpesuV2PLDM=` encrypted using DES (password is: `pass`) for which I'm using the following command

```
des -d -in Encrypted.txt -out normal.txt
```

for which I'm getting bad magic number error after entering the password: pass

Encrypted.txt contains the encrypted message `U2FsdGVkX18ztmw81FTK/c+jAf8xtcZdIpesuV2PLDM=`
and normal.txt is empty

I searched all the posts in stack overflow and found no article which could solve my problem, Please help get this issue solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The input to the `des` command shouldn't be in base64. Instead, you need to first decode the base64 output and then provide it to the OpenSSL `des` command. For instance, when I run the following on Linux:

`echo U2FsdGVkX18ztmw81FTK/c+jAf8xtcZdIpesuV2PLDM= | openssl enc -base64 -d | openssl des -d`

I get the correct output:

`hello world`

Since Windows is not great with pipes, you have to redirect the output to intermediate files and then run individual `openssl` commands.

Comment: Is it mandatory to encode the message into base64 before decypting it ?

Comment: No. base64 is just a convenient way of representing unprintable characters. If the encrypted message is in base64 format, you have to decode it before decrypting it. In fact, openssl's `des` command has an in-built base64 encode/decode option (`-a`). So, all you need to do is `openssl des -d -a -in Encrypted.txt -out normal.txt`

Comment: yes execcuted that command and I still get "Bad Magic Number error"

Comment: it contains just this "U2FsdGVkX18ztmw81FTK/c+jAf8xtcZdIpesuV2PLDM= "

Comment: I even tried the above command on Windows and it works. The only suggestion I have at this point is to make sure there is a newline at the end in `Encrypted.txt`. If none, then OpenSSL will give a `"error reading input file"` error. The only way OpenSSL will give a `"bad magic number"` error is if the base64-decoded output doesn't begin with the string `Salted__` or you did not specify `-a` in the command line. I verified that if the string you pasted above is base64-decoded, the first 8 characters are indeed `Salted__`. So, make sure you definitely supply a `-a`.

Answer (score 3):

Openssl can base64 decode and decrypt in the same step with the `-a` or `-base64` switch. But there is a bug in openssl's base64 processing, it expects a newline at the end of the base64 encoded data.

**The easiest solution** is to `base64 --decode` before decrypting.

For example, consider this base64 encrypted output:

```
# echo foo | openssl enc -aes256 -md sha512 -pass pass:pass -e -base64

U2FsdGVkX182tdJx07S5YoPzi9XhyONdR8Xbc6V1jiw=
```

If this is sent with a newline, it works fine. But if not, it fails.

```
# echo 'U2FsdGVkX182tdJx07S5YoPzi9XhyONdR8Xbc6V1jiw=' | openssl enc -aes256 -md sha512 -pass pass:pass -d -base64

foo

# echo -n 'U2FsdGVkX182tdJx07S5YoPzi9XhyONdR8Xbc6V1jiw=' | openssl enc -aes256 -md sha512 -pass pass:pass -d -base64

error reading input file
```

You can insert the newline with cat, or decode the base64 with another utility first:

```
# echo -n 'U2FsdGVkX182tdJx07S5YoPzi9XhyONdR8Xbc6V1jiw=' | cat - <(echo "") | openssl enc -aes256 -md sha512 -pass pass:pass -d -base64

foo

# echo -n 'U2FsdGVkX182tdJx07S5YoPzi9XhyONdR8Xbc6V1jiw=' | base64 --decode | openssl enc -aes256 -md sha512 -pass pass:pass -d

foo
```

Comment: Good point.  What did you want your example openssl to show?  I get `foo` from `echo -n 'Zm9vCg==' | base64 --decode`, regardless of the `openssl` command on macos.

Comment: Thanks @rustyMagnet, my answer was a little confusing, improved the examples now!